# Assign several values to a single matrix element

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, matrix

Is there an easy way to assign a vector to a matrix element or a 2-dimensional array?

```
array = data.frame(array(numeric(), c(rows, columns))) # generates empty array

array[i,j] = c(value1,value2)
```

The idea above results the following error:
`replacement has 2 rows, data has 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it must be stored in a single element, I only can imagine to store the vector as a string. Of course this requires conversion forth and back with careful choice of the separator.

```
array[i, j] = paste(c(value1, value2), collapse=" ")

v = as.numeric(strsplit(array[i, j], " ", 0)[[1]]) # assumed numeric values
```